# locking a table just for my query during an update?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using mysql 5.5.22.
Sometimes it happens that I need to take some data from somewhere and this somewhere is a system table.

E.g.:

I have this query (written by my colleague):

```
UPDATE _x_eia_marcatura AS X, A_EVENTS AS E 
SET X.kind = E.kind, X.ref_id = E.ref_id 
WHERE E.DELIVERY_ID=49 AND E.kind='c' AND E.ref_id = 69 
AND X.MAILQ_ID = E.MAILQ_ID;
```

Now if you by accident write E.kind = X.kind you're updating the system table. Is there a way to tell mysql "if I'm updating table E then don't do anything" ?

I know that this alias naming convention is crappy but it made me think maybe there is a way to do something I suggested.

Comment: Can you issue a "lock table" on table E prior to updating it in your program?

Comment: The problem is we have some not automatic operations (I know, I told them!) and we need to rely on system tables that cannot be locked for any reason. I just want a check on my query that it's not doing damages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use permissions if it's a global "never insert into this table" thing, or perhaps triggers.

Generally speaking though, no. Code is normally considered "trusted" so whatever it asks for is considered acceptable. If you really need this, you should investigate stored procedures and only allow database changes through these.

Comment: This table is used by the system so it can't be locked or anything. I just wanted something to check at the query level.

Comment: Stored procedure sounds like the way to go.

Comment: Then no. There's no magical way you can tell MySQL to "block updates to this table if there's also an update to this other table". Stored Procs are your only option really.